# Laptop camera. How to get detailed information about it?

Tags: hardware

My Samsung laptop has a built-in camera. The camera works fine.

I want to get detailed information on it, at the very least model and communication bus.

The output of `lsusb`, `lspci`, `lshw`, `ls /dev` do not show anything interesting ... or do they? Maybe I do not know what to look for!

Comment: Hm ... `SC-13HDL11939N`. But no datasheet online, so I'm going down to search for the driver and ask it questions :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your camera is on USB. You should really try verbose versions of the commands:

```
lsusb -v | less
```

There are lots of things to browse through. You might also want to try

```
lsmod | grep video
```

or just `lsmod` to find an interesting kernel module. Once found, try `modinfo` on it's name.

Comment: So muuuuuuuch information. I found the camera on the usb bus, and much more, than what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!